# Is an app contained in a docker container more easy to sysadmin?

Tags: performance, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

What is the point of building an nginx (it's a web server) docker image on top of a linux (let's say centOS) scratch docker image/file, if the host server machine is already running on that OS ?

Does it consumes any more "CPU space" ? RAM ? File storage ? How much more proportionnally ?

E.g - I have my OS, my service, its dependencies. Then if I want to use a docker container of that app or service, it will store a whole OS image uselessly, and a whole dependency image uselessly, right ? So even if many apps in the future need the same dependency image that will only be stored once and for all, I will require to have it under the "image format" in addition of the native install of that dependency on my system, right? How much the "docker engine" takes in storage space?

Should I install all the services composing my server machine as docker containers, or should I "source" install each of them? Is a mix of these approaches worth it? Would you guys have some examples?

Comment: shortened version of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61003951/in-which-case-should-i-use-a-docker-container-rather-than-a-vm-or-a-source-insta that may be closed for "too broad" reason

Comment: Shortened, yes, but there are still 11 question marks. What is the specific, practical problem you are facing?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1010708/can-a-unique-server-machine-have-several-ip-for-different-services